# Migrating a Drupal Node.js website from localhost to web server

Tags: nodes, migrations

Due to specific website feature requirements, which do not seem to be possible in Drupal 7 without Node.js integration, I am strongly considering to integrate Drupal 7 with Node.js modules offering real time interactivity. I understand the basic concepts however I have never actually used Node.js on a website before. I have installed Node.js on my computer under Program Files (Windows) and begun testing the integration with a test website on localhost (WAMP).

My concern is for when I later will need to migrate a client's website to an actual web server. I would like to ask those who have had some experience with such Drupal/Node.js integration, what is a streamlined workflow for migration. For example, I am wondering if Node.js should be installed into the same folder as the website directory instead of Program Files, so that when testing is finished I will be able to ftp the entire website directory with the Node.js installation without needing to reinstall Node.js and reconfigure everything. I am not sure if copying everything over would work or if Node.js needs to be installed again separately on the web server?

I would like to get a clearer understanding of this process before I make the leap into Node.js integration with future client websites. I believe Node.js integration introduces some great new features however it could potentially be a giant can of worms if not handled properly.

Comment: I can't see a Drupal-related question here (just asking about installing/migrating a node.js application). If there's a Drupal-related aspect, other than the fact that you happen to have a Drupal site _connecting_ to your node.js server, please update the question with those details and flag for re-opening

Comment: The question is concerned specifically with migrating a Drupal website with Node.js integration; therefore outlining a workflow to have both systems working side by side. Posting this on Stack Overflow is likely to be flagged as excessively "Drupal specific".

Comment: As far as the Drupal site is concerned you need do nothing but copy the files across. Setting up the node.js server isn't something we'd cover here though. There isn't such a concept as a Drupal Node server; Drupal is Drupal, Node is Node. Once you've got a Node server set up, and the application installed and configured, Drupal will be able to connect to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical NodeJS setup usually involves a Linux server and a nginx web server/proxy that delegates the requests to the application running on a specific/semi-random unprivileged port. In other words, nginx will have a site declaration (vhost) for your Drupal and a another site declaration for your NodeJS application. Your NodeJS application runs in the backgrounds and listens for requests from nginx.

NodeJS itself is usually installed through the Linux distribution's packaging system, similarly to PHP.

On the filesystem, I would treat the two applications as separate projects, in two separate directories on the server. It's pretty rare to find developers who have a good understanding both Drupal/PHP and NodeJS, so keeping it separate will make it easier for other people eventually working on that project to familiarize themselves with the environment.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I don't use Linux at all so I am planning to test this on Windows, I assume this is possible since there is a Node.js installer for Windows.

For the migration, when I am choosing a host how can I determine whether their server is able to run Node.js alongside my Drupal website? Are there specific requirements that will be needed for this to work? I am not that familiar with servers, so will I need to simply copy/ftp the Node.js files or do some sort of manual install of Node.js on the server?

Comment: There are many ways to configure NodeJS, but most typically it's on a VPS. However, I have to agree with Clive. The basic answer is that yes, those are two separate apps, and should be managed separately, as any other two web app/services that talk to each other. Beyond that, it's offtopic for this forum. There are lots of good resources on Stack Exchange to learn more about NodeJS. Good luck!